# Run Powershell script every hour on Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, backup, azure-sql-database, schedule

I have found [this great script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Backup-Azure-SQL-Databases-bbeea33e#content) which backs up SQL Azure database to BLOB.

I want to run many different variations of this script - e.g. DB1 goes to Customer1Blob, DB2 goes to Customer2Blob.

I have looked at Scheduler Job Collections. However I can only see options (Action settings) for HTTP(S)/ Storage Queue / Service Bus.

Is it possible to run a specific .ps1 script (with commands) scheduled?

Comment: Another way to do that would be Azure Functions

Comment: @4c74356b41 can you use powershell in Functions?  Or does it have to be converted to an exe?

Comment: you can use it natively

Comment: @4c74356b41 should I follow this to get started on your path please ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer

Comment: yeah, or just go to function app and create a powershell function with timer, thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely run a Powershell script as a WebJob. If you want to run a script on a schedule, you can add a settings.job file containing a chron expression with your webjob. The docs for doing so are [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#user-content-scheduling-a-triggered-webjob).

Answer (score 2):

For this type of automation tasks, I prefer to use the Azure Automation service.  You can create runbooks using powershell and then schedule this with the use of the Azure scheduler.  You can have it run "on azure" so you do not need to use compute power that you pay for (rather you pay by the minute the job runs) or you can configure it to run with a hybrid worker.

For more information, please see [the documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/)

Answer (score 0):

When exporting from SQL DB or from SQL Server, make sure you are exporting from a quiescent database. Exporting from a database with active transactions can result in data integrity issues - data being added to various tables while they are also being exported.